# Use 'map' to show the count of first elements in each tuple

Tags: python, map-function

I am working with RDD pipelines and trying to use 'map' to show the count of first elements in each tuple. For example, the first should produce 2, second 1, third 3.

```
   [('John', 'MA'), ('Sam', 'PA')],
     [('Ryan', 'NM')],
     [('John', 'DE'), ('Stephanie', 'CA'), ('Courtney', 'ME')]
```

I believe it should be something like this line of code:

```
names.map(lambda name: (name.count[0]))
```

Comment: Seems a Python-only issue. Not clear why you added tags _pyspark_ and _rdd_. Please show the __definition of var `names`__ (best as python code) as well as the mapped output that was not as expected.

Comment: Something like this - `size = [len(tpl) for tpl in data]`   assuming your input is `data`.   For this case, don't need `map`.

Comment: can't you just use len?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be much faster as a list comprehension:

```
data = [[('John', 'MA'), ('Sam', 'PA')],[('Ryan', 'NM')],[('John', 'DE'), ('Stephanie', 'CA'), ('Courtney', 'ME')]]

out = [ len(x) for x in data ]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 3]
```

But if you *really* want it as a lambda map, this should work:

```
out = map(lambda x: len(x), data)
```

Comment: No only faster, but also cleaner and more "pythonic".